# How to recover all FAT partition files on NOOBS Raspberry card

Tags: noobs

When I inserted my brand new NOOBS card in my windows computer I observed windows was able to detect only 56 MB on card. As card was 8GB I formatted it with windows computer as FAT drive.

Later after searching web I founf out NOOBS card has 3 to 4 linux based partitions on card which are not detected by windows and only FAT system (56 MB) is visible to windows.

Can anyone tell me when I formatted by NOOBS card FAT file system partition which files should I place back to make the NOOBS image working back again ??

Comment: You should open up the card on Linux, or use some kind of DD under Win.

Comment: http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md Note the Windows section

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a 'brand new' SD card, simply reflash Noobs. Instructions [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/).

Comment: There is still one problem. Windows doesnt detect partitions and still shows only 56MB available on card !!!

Comment: I tried software Like SDCardFormatter from (https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_windows/index.html) but it fails to format my drive saying its Write-Protected. My SD card adapters write lock is OFF I double checked it.